# Proper design of database fetch when app is launching

Tags: ios, iphone, multithreading

Maybe this is very repeated question and I'm sorry if so, but after reading all similar subjects & tutorials and trying by many different ways, I'm always unable to have a proper design. So I tried to be pragmatic and simplify things the most as follow:

My app fetches 3 SQL queries which are pretty quick but they contain all needed information for the app. So I would wait for them before I can refresh UI controls.
I perform db fetch by creating 3 separates NSURLSessionDataTask in a singleton class. Something like:

```
-(void)fetchdb {
   [self runDataTask:request1];
   [self runDataTask:request2];
   [self runDataTask:request3];
}

-(void)runDataTask: request {
   NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request];
   [dataTask resume];
}
```

I call this fetch in viewDidLoad of the initial view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [mySingletonClass fetchDb:self];
    // other stuffs
}
```

When didCompleteWithError from NSURLSessionDelegate of all three tasks is called and all my three lists build by task 1, 2 and 3 are filled, I call refreshAll method of my initial view controller:

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task
didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error{
  if (error == nil){
     [self.delegate buildTargetList];
     if (list1.count>0 && list2.count>0 && list3.count>0)
        [initialViewController refreshAll];
  }
}
```

Finally refreshAll refreshes all UI by a dispatch_sync from main_queue (I have to use sync because in the same block I would first fill Arrays used by UI that I want to refresh):

```
-(void)refreshAll {
   dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
       [self buildAllLocalArraysForAllUIByUsingSingletonClassLists];
       [self refreshAllUI];
   });
}
```

The result's:
Most of time, it works fine but I have sometimes unexpected behaviours such as:

- “Collection <__NSArrayM: 0xb1a2970> was mutated while being enumerated”
- NSRangeException
- or I discovered that refreshAll might not be called at all or strangely is called twice!

Could anyone help me to understand what am I doing wrong or if my design is totally wrong? I'm very very new to IOS dev. Thanks.

Comment: What does buildTargetList do and how does it know which queries have returned? Is it getting called on different threads for each result?

Comment: I didn't reflect it to be as simple as possible but in fact methods which create datatask and launch queries are encapsulated in a separate class (lets call it ServiceConnector). There is string label in ServiceConnector class, when I instantiate it for each query, I attribute a specific label so when didCompleteWithError is called, I pass the label to the delegate method in singleton class. So I know over there, results are related to which query and I build the related array with fetched results.